# How to produce double quotes instead of single quotes for XML attributes in CL-WHO

Tags: common-lisp, cl-who

By default, CL-WHO uses single quotes for quoting XML attributes values (e.g. `<h1 id='title'>Hello!</h1>`). I am trying to set `cl-who:*attribute-quote-char*` to `#\"` so that attribute values use double quotes instead (e.g. `<h1 id="title">Hello!</h1>`). However, `(setq cl-who:*attribute-quote-char #\")` does not seem to have any effect when I use it in ASDF like this:

`myprog.asd`:

```lisp
(defpackage myprog-asd
  (:use :cl :asdf))
(in-package :myprog-asd)

(defsystem "myprog"
  :depends-on (:cl-who)
  :components ((:file "mypackage")))
```

`mypackage.lisp`:

```lisp
(defpackage :mypackage
  (:use :cl)
  (:export :f))
(in-package :mypackage)

(setq cl-who:*attribute-quote-char* #\")  ;; <- HERE.

(defun f ()
  (cl-who:with-html-output (*standard-output*)
    (:h1 :id "title" "Hello!")))
```

I am getting single quotes instead of double quotes:

```
$ sbcl
* (require "asdf")
* (asdf:load-asd (merge-pathnames "myprog.asd" (uiop:getcwd)))
* (asdf:load-system :myprog)
* (mypackage:f)
<h1 id='title'>Hello!</h1>
```

Why is `(setq cl-who:*attribute-quote-char #\")` not having any effect? How do I make CL-WHO print double quotes instead of single quotes?

(SBCL version: 2.2.2, CL-WHO version: 1.1.4 [commit: 0d382647])

---

By the way, I found that I could get double quotes by wrapping the `setq` in an `eval-when`:

```lisp
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :execute)
  (setq cl-who:*attribute-quote-char* #\"))
```

However, I have no idea how or why this works.

Comment: Note: ASDF highly recommends to *always* load a .asd file with `asdf:load-asd` and *not* `cl:load`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because `with-html-output` is smart enough to spot (some, it necessarily can not spot all) cases where the generated HTML is a constant string.  In those cases it just turns the whole thing into a macroexpansion-time constant.  and that happens before you have assigned to the variable, which happens at load time.  That's why wrapping it with `(eval-when (... :compile-toplevel) ...)` works.